# Procedural generation of genus $k$ tori triangle meshes

Tags: mesh, triangulation, procedural-generation

I am looking for code or pseudo-code for the generation of genus $k$ tori triangle meshes. I want to get something like in the image [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_sum). Book/paper references, code, github links, etc. are all welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't leave a comment, because I don't have enough reputation points.

Do you know how to represent your objects using an *implicit* function like f(x, y, z)? If so, then you can use Marching Cubes or Dual Contouring, or some similar algorithm to convert that field into a triangle mesh.

As you can see in the source, the tori are multiplied together, and a non-zero isovalue is used.

The final code is at: https://github.com/sjhalayka/k-genus_torus

[image: genus 5 tori]

Comment: I assume you meant implicit function, e.g. $f(x,y,z) = 0$, and not parametric function, e.g. $(x(u,v), y(u,v), z(u,v))$. But yes, I could theoretically use an implicit function where I smooth merge two tori sdfs.

Comment: My bad, I appreciate the correction. I changed the answer.

Comment: @lightxbulb I altered the answer.