# k-torus code in C++

Tags: computational-geometry

I've been trying to implement this k-torus code that I found, but all it does is return a cylinder (torus of outer radius infinity). Is there anything that I'm missing here?

```
#include "main.h"

float f(const float x, const int n)
{
    float result = 1.0;

    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        const float i_float = static_cast<float>(i);

        result *= (result - (i_float - 1.0f)) * (result - i_float);
    }

    return result;
}

float g(const float x, const float y, const int n) 
{
    return f(x, n) + powf(y, 2.0);
}

float h(const float x, const float y, const float z, const int n, const float r, const float R)
{
    return powf(g(x, y, n), 1.0) + powf(z, 2.0) - powf(r, 2.0);
}


int main(void)
{
    const float grid_max = 10.0;
    const float grid_min = -grid_max;
    const size_t res = 100;
    const bool make_border = true;
    const float isovalue = 0.1f;
    const float border_value = 1.0f + isovalue;
    const int n = 2;
    const float radius = 0.1f;
    const float outer_radius = 1.0f;


    vector<triangle> triangles;
    vector<float> xyplane0(res*res, 0);
    vector<float> xyplane1(res*res, 0);

    const float step_size = (grid_max - grid_min) / (res - 1);

    size_t z = 0;

    vertex_3 pos(grid_min, grid_min, grid_min);

    // Calculate xy plane 0.
    for (size_t x = 0; x < res; x++, pos.x += step_size)
    {
        pos.y = grid_min;

        for (size_t y = 0; y < res; y++, pos.y += step_size)
        {
            if (true == make_border && (x == 0 || y == 0 || z == 0 || x == res - 1 || y == res - 1 || z == res - 1))
                xyplane0[x * res + y] = border_value;
            else
                xyplane0[x * res + y] = h(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z, n, radius, outer_radius);
        }
    }

    // Prepare for xy plane 1.
    z++;
    pos.z += step_size;

    size_t box_count = 0;

    // Calculate xy planes 1 and greater.
    for (; z < res; z++, pos.z += step_size)
    {
        pos.x = grid_min;

        cout << "Calculating triangles from xy-plane pair " << z << " of " << res - 1 << endl;

        for (size_t x = 0; x < res; x++, pos.x += step_size)
        {
            pos.y = grid_min;

            for (size_t y = 0; y < res; y++, pos.y += step_size)
            {
                if (true == make_border && (x == 0 || y == 0 || z == 0 || x == res - 1 || y == res - 1 || z == res - 1))
                    xyplane1[x * res + y] = border_value;
                else
                    xyplane1[x * res + y] = h(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z, n, radius, outer_radius);
            }
        }

        tesselate_adjacent_xy_plane_pair(
            box_count,
            xyplane0, xyplane1,
            z - 1,
            triangles,
            isovalue,
            grid_min, grid_max, res,
            grid_min, grid_max, res,
            grid_min, grid_max, res);

        xyplane1.swap(xyplane0);
    }

    cout << endl;

    if (0 < triangles.size())
        write_triangles_to_binary_stereo_lithography_file(triangles, "out.stl");

    // Print box-counting dimension
    // Make sure that step_size != 1.0f :)
    cout << "Box counting dimension: " << logf(static_cast<float>(box_count)) / logf(1.0f/step_size) << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

[image]

The relevant documents are at:

[Procedural generation of genus $k$ tori triangle meshes](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/13794/procedural-generation-of-genus-k-tori-triangle-meshes)

and

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152256/implicit-equation-for-double-torus-genus-2-orientable-surface

and

https://github.com/sjhalayka/k-torus

Answer (score 2):

As you will see in the code, the tori are multiplied together, and a non-zero isovalue is used.

The final code is at: https://github.com/sjhalayka/k-genus_torus

[image: genus 5 tori]

[image]

Comment: did you use some library to implement that?

Comment: The code is all open source. I used some of the code from Paul Bourke's website -- https://paulbourke.net/geometry/polygonise/ --, and the rest of the code is mine. No external libraries are needed.